# python ImportError: cannot import name _vq

Tags: python, importerror

I am facing a problem with import upon running the following line:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
```

Context: I need this for hierarchical cluster analysis.

The error message I receive is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "\pyshell#14>", line 1, in \module>
>
> from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
>
> File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster__init__.py", line 27, in \module>
>   from . import vq, hierarchy
>
> File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\vq.py", line 89, in \module>
>     from . import _vq
>
> ImportError: cannot import name _vq

The error relates to importing _vq which is called from the vq.py. I checked circularity, updating setuptools etc as suggested in forums and this blog 
http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html
 but none of this seems to be material to the problem.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try reinstalling scipy.Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: Did you install `numpy` ?

Comment: Thanks. I have installed both scipy and numpy and tried various variations (loading numpy first, scipy first, after etc). I am on Windows.

Comment: Try uninstall scipy and reinstall it. I had the same issue and uninstalled it (it updated several other packages during the uninstallation), and reinstalled it and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should update the scipy package:

```
pip install --upgrade scipy
```